# Multiple applications accessing the same mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb

Application A opens mongodb and reads a document.  The document now exists in Application A's memory.  Application B, perhaps running on a different box (but in this case as a mock running in a different process on the same box) inserts data into the document.  When does Application A see application B's change?

Mongo is configured to use safe writes and a journal.  There is only the one shard.

Mongo updates are written immediately to the journal, but updates to the data file can take 60 seconds (syncdelay=60).  How is this supposed to work when two different applications share the same instance?

Answer (score 1):

When A queries for the document again.

You should take a look at the [WriteConcern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) you are using.

Comment: Not helpful.  Application B's changes have not yet been flushed to the data file so when Application A queries the document those changes are not yet there.  I worked around the issue locally by setting in my /etc/mongod.conf file a new line
syncdelay=20

This reduces the flush to disk interval from every 60 seconds to every 20 seconds.  Which in my particular case was enough.  But this is a special case solution.  What is the general solution?

Comment: Looked at WriteConcern before I asked my question.  We are using journaled.  But all this does is guarantee that the journal is updated, not that the data file that other mongodb users read from is updated.  Updates get flushed to permanent storage (by default) only every 60 seconds.  We are not replica sets; There is only one primary.

Comment: The behavior that is stumping me is that the Journal appears to use a different  commitIntervalMs under OS/X then it does under Centos 7.  Centos is always seeing the full 60 second latency while OS/X appears to be seeing a reduced value.  Tests that pass on OS/X fail under Centos.  On Centos, remote debugger stops show conclusively that the in memory objects have the correct value after a mongodb update while RoboMongo shows that the physical data file has not yet been updated.

Comment: Turns out that the other systems had nojournal=true set in their /etc/mongod.conf file.  That is, they were not journaling.  This may account for the different behavior that I was observing on my system which had in turn prompted this question.  They should be journaling their updates.

Comment: The application has a JMS queue in the loop. My guess is that JMS is not configured for inprocess.  The receiver is accessing Mongodb but in a different process space and before mongodb in the sender's process space has flushed its updates.